# Why SSLSocket, subtype of socket, lacking create_connection method?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, python-2.6

Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket) states:

> ssl.wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None, server_side=False, cert_reqs=CERT_NONE, ssl_version={see docs}, ca_certs=None, do_handshake_on_connect=True, suppress_ragged_eofs=True)
>   Takes an instance sock of socket.socket, and returns an instance of ssl.SSLSocket, a subtype of socket.socket, which wraps the underlying socket in an SSL context.

But when I try to use the SSL socket's [create_connection](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) method, I receive a:

```
ssl_sock.create_connection(('www.google.com', 443))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'create_connection'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_connection()` is a function in the `socket` module that creates a new socket, connects it, and then returns it<sup>1</sup>. The method on socket objects is [`connect()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect), which accepts the same address tuple as `create_connection()`:

```python
ssl_socket.connect(("...", 443))
```

Unfortunately, in the documentation for the `socket` module, it's easy to confuse them. You need to check which part of the page you're on. Methods on socket objects are found only in the [Socket Objects](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/socket.html#socket-objects) section, and the prefix to the methods is "`socket.`", meaning "a method of the `socket.socket` type", which turns out to be identical to the "`socket.`" prefix for the other functions in the module, where it means "a function of the `socket` module".

<sup>1</sup>When the docs say "the socket", they mean the socket that was created in the function, even though they don't ever *say* that a socket is created.